# error creating alias while using hibernate inheritance table per concrete class

Tags: java, hibernate, polymorphism

I have a model where I implemented table per concrete class. So I have an abstract class having the common properties across multiple tables. and I have the following entities.

```
    @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
    public abstract class BaseForm{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    protected Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id=id;
    }

    @Column(name = "submission_date")
    protected Date submissionDate;

    public Date getSubmissionDate() {
        return submissionDate;
    }
    public void setSubmissionDate(Date submissionDate) {
        this.submissionDate=submissionDate;
    }

   }

@Entity
@Table(name = "form_a")
public class FormA extends BaseForm{

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "formA", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade(value = org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @OrderBy("id")
    protected List<UserForm> userForms = new ArrayList<UserForm>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "form_b")
public class FormB extends BaseForm{

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "formB", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade(value = org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @OrderBy("id")
    protected List<UserForm> userForms = new ArrayList<UserForm>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_form")
public class UserForm {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    protected FormA formA;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    protected FormB formB;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    protected User user;
```

}

But whenever I try to use createAlias on the polymorphic query selecting all the forms joining userForms to return the user information for each form. It raises an exception.
2016-01-04 12:21:54,158 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] Not unique table/alias: 'userforms1_'

```
    DetachedCriteria baseCR = DetachedCriteria.forClass(BaseForm.class);
    baseCR.createAlias("userForms", "userForms");
            );
    baseCR.add(Restrictions.disjunction()
        .add(Restrictions.isNotNull("userForms.formA"))
        .add(Restrictions.isNotNull("userForms.formB"))
    ); 
    baseCR.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    baseCR.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
    List results= ht.findByCriteria(baseCR);
```

Here is the generated hibernate query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS y0_
FROM
  (SELECT id,
    submissionDate,  
    1 AS clazz_
  FROM form_a
  UNION
  SELECT id,
    submissionDate,  
    2 AS clazz_
  FROM form_b
  ) this_
INNER JOIN user_form userforms1_
ON this_.id=userforms1_.formA_id
INNER JOIN user_form userforms1_
ON this_.id=userforms1_.formB_id
WHERE (userforms1_.formA IS NOT NULL
OR userforms1_.formB IS NOT NULL)
```

Any idea what would be the problem. and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing subclass fields with a superclass alias, which is conceptually wrong (although works in some situations, but obviously not always).

You should consider moving `userForms` to the base class or transforming your query to something like this (JPQL, just translate it to an equivalent Criteria):

```
select bf from BaseForm bf 
  where bf.id in (select fa.id from FormA fa join fa.userForms)
     or bf.id in (select fb.id from FormB fb join fb.userForms)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. but actually that hql doesn't solve the problem because FormA and FormB everyone has it's own id sequence. so it's possible that we have ID10 in FormA and another ID 10 in FormB

Comment: In that case I'm afraid you've got much larger problem than this. What is the expected result of: `entityManager.find(BaseForm.class, 10)` (or the equivalent operation with Hibernate `Session`)?

Comment: I see your point @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE) would take care of the uniqueness of the ids across all the entities.